# React Redux, replacing state history

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am developing an app where I have one Canvas. 
Users can choose to duplicate this canvas to save their achievement.

My question is when they come back to this canvas, is it possible to erase the actual state history and replace it by the canvas one in react-redux ?
Is there an efficient way to replace a state history by another in redux?

I could try by directly changing it in the store, but it's a bit dirty...

Here is some snippets of my code:

**Store**

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({
       historyCanvas,
       canvasDrawing
}));
```

**Reducers**

```
var stateCanvasDrawing = {
  lines = [{id:1, strokes: [..] }, {id:2, strokes: [..] }] 
}
var stateHistoryCanvas = {
  history = [{id: history1, state: {present: [..], past: [..], future:[..]}]
```

I store states in the historyCanvas reducers: 
Then by clicking on a icon, I am able to retrieve the state I want to replace:

```
var tempState = state.stateHistoryCanvas[0]['state'];
```

And then I want to do something like that:

```
store.getState()['stateCanvasDrawing'] = tempState;
```

in order to replace the actual state by the state I retrieve. 
That would be easy with just redux.

But I'm using redux-undo, so how could I copy the entire history I have stored in 'stateHistoryCanvas' to the new state? I don't want to copy only the 
but also the `state['future'] state['past']`

Hope it's clear,

Thank you all,

Comment: Yes, your reducer could just return an entirely new state. Could you post some snippets to the relevant parts of your code? It's easier to discuss actual code than theory.

Comment: As the previous comment notes, we really need to see some code to properly answer, but I think in general if you are using Redux you should keep the state in the store and access it from there as much as possible. It can be annoying but is much more robust at scale. If your app is going to be very small, you might want to consider not using Redux at all.

Comment: Apparently you will need just return another state to your reducer, but you should really post you code so that we could discuss it better!

Comment: @mccambridge, I have updated my answer. Hope you wil understand it